# Google Apps Script: How do I change my displayed selection with for class listBox code?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script

I have an on click event that changes some form Class TextBox values to null using the following

app.getElementById("name").setText("")

How do I change my displayed selection for class listBox code?

looking at class listbox

I thought it might be something like

app.getElementById("relationship").setItemText("** Please Select **","** Please Select **")

but that doesn't work

Any ideas?

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box?hl=es

Your listbox should already have the dummy item in the list from when it was created, but if not, you need to use the first argument of setItemText to specify the index of the new item (0).

Once the dummy item is present, you can reset the control using the setSelectedIndex method. Check the documentation for specifics.

Comment: Thank-you! 'app.getElementById("relationship").setSelectedIndex(0)' worked perfectly